# How can I make an input text field redirect to a new file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text field where someone can type into it. I want to make it so when someone hits the submit button it takes them to another page about what they said. In this case, the input field will be filled with countries, so if someone typed "Iceland" it would take them to a page titled "iceland.html".

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut-icon" src="img/seychelles.gif">
    <title>Flag Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flag Projector</h1>
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <div class="autocomplete">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Territory" name="Flag" id="myInput">
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
    var currentFocus;
    if (inp) {
        inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            var a, b, i, val = this.value;
            closeAllLists();
            if (!val) {
                return false;
            }
            currentFocus = -1;
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
            this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                    b = document.createElement("DIV");
                    b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                    b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                    b.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                        inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        closeAllLists();
                    });
                    a.appendChild(b);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (inp) {
        inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                currentFocus++;
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                currentFocus--;
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keycode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    if (currentFocus > -1) {
                    if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                }
            }
        });
     }
    function addActive(x){
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x){
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active")
        }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt){
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), array);
```

If you can solve this, could you please explain in simple terms? I am new to coding and may have a hard time understanding difficult code. Thank you

Comment: Also if you need clarification I am willing to help articulate my question :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the `<form>`'s behavior, but you can use JS to do a `location.assign("/" + input.value + ".html")` when they submit the form

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Totally possible... assuming you control/can alter the backend app server :)

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms so, would input.value be the country (in previous example, Iceland)? And if input is a new variable, what would I make it equal to?

Comment: Oh yeah and thanks for such quick responses you two :)

Comment: @Anon1776 Well, `location.assign` changes the current URL, so you'd do something like `location.assign("iceland.html")` to go to the `iceland.html` page. I used `input.value` as a placeholder, with `input` being your `myInput`, but you could do things like check if against a list of known countries, or lowercase it.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Ok, thank you. I will try this when I get a minute and tell you how it goes.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Hmm, that didn't work, could you please explain?